# Can a smartcontract offer free gas

Tags: solidity, gas-price

I have wrote a smartcontract which will be called by a mobile device.

This device will be outside. It embbed a software wallet (private key). But this wallet will own 0 ether because the device can be stolen.

So the device won’t be able to spend any gas.

What i want to do is to put some ether on the smartcontract address.

I want to know if it is possible to do this: when the mobile device calls a smartcontract function : the gas should be payed by the contract himself.

Of course i will add a logic which will only allow my device to call the function.

Thanks

Comment: No, an account needs ether in order to execute a transaction (and that includes a transaction which calls a smart-contract function).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do that. In order for a transaction to be valid and execute sender's account should hold at least **Vo** ethers which are paid up front.

`Vo = Tg * Tp + Tv`

Where:

- **Tg** is the gasLimit you've specified
- **Tp** is the gasPrice you've specified
- **Tv** is the amount of wei to be transferred to the recipient's account

Note that you need to pay for the whole amount of gas specified by gasLimit before the transaction. You will be refunded for any unused gas after the transaction is completed.

You can find more info about this subject in ethereum's [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf). I will quote some parts related to your question for your ease:

> Every transaction has a specific amount of gas associated with it: gasLimit. This is the amount of gas which is implicitly purchased from the sender's account balance. The purchase happens at the according gasPrice, also specified in the transaction. The transaction is considered invalid if the account balance cannot support such a purchase. It is named gasLimit since any unused gas at the end of the transaction is refunded (at the same rate of purchase) to the sender's account. Gas does not exist outside of the execution of a transaction. Thus for accounts with trusted code associated, a relatively high gas limit may be set and left alone

> It is assumed that any transactions executed first pass the initial tests of intrinsic validity. These include:
>
> (1) The transaction is well-formed RLP, with no additional trailing bytes;
>
> (2) the transaction signature is valid;
>
> (3) the transaction nonce is valid (equivalent to the sender account's current nonce);
>
> (4) the gas limit is no smaller than the intrinsic gas, g0, used by the transaction; and
>
> (5) the sender account balance contains at least the cost, v0, required in up-front payment.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if it is possible to do this: when the mobile device calls a smartcontract function : the gas should be payed by the contract himself.

Currently this is not possible in Ethereum. It is an inherit limitation of current Ethereum design, but for example possible on the EOS blockhain.

There exist attempts to address this shortcoming, by building relay layers on the top of Ethereum, in their own networks. One is [Gas Station Network](https://docs.opengsn.org/learn/), but I do not know if the project is still alive or functional.

Some smart contract-based wallets like Pillar and Argent have centralised servers that pay the transaction fee for the user. Design is pretty complex, but these wallets are open source and you can study them how they do it.